# Postman Pre-Requisite Script: Store Email ID based on Random First name and Last name

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am struggling here to generate an email ID that consists of Random First name and Random Last name. I don't want to use the dynamic Variable $randomEmail because it generates any random email which is totally different from the First name and Last name and looks very unrealistic.

I have a Pre-Requisite Script in Postman, Where I have two environment variables first_name and last_name, I use the faker library to generate dummy data as Following. The dynamic variable $randomFirstName and $randomLastName, generate and set the Environment variables as following.
Let assume that $randomFirstName=John and $randomLastName=Doe

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("first_name", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomFirstName}}'));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("last_name", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomFirstName}}'));
```

Now I want to use the Environment variable first_name and last_name to use in the following variable email_formatted to generate the email ID which is consisting of first name and last name.

```
email_formatted = "{{first_name}}" + '_' + "{{last_name}}" + '@gmail.com';
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("email", email_formatted);
console.log("Email: " + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("email"));
```

However, on the Consol, I am getting the following result.

ACTUAL "Email: {{first_name}}_{{last_name}}@gmail.com"

EXPECTED "Email: John_Doe@gmail.com"

I think I am doing some small mistakes here in syntax or how the Environment variables are used in the Pre-Requisite Script. Thanks for your time in reading, and any leads would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
email_formatted = pm.environment.get("first_name") + '_' + pm.environment.get("last_name") + '@gmail.com';
pm.environment.set("email", email_formatted);
console.log("Email: " + pm.environment.get("email"));
```

in postman we can refer variable as {{variablename}} only in non script sessions. In script you have use

```
pm.environment.get('varaiblename')
```

to access environment varaible ,to access other varaibles use as pm.globals, pm.variables etc

As Danny pointed out postman is moving to new pm.* API , and going to deprecate postman.* in future  .

So start using the new api as the documentation is extensively updated and available mostly for pm.* Api .

**Note:** setnextrequest , is still available  only through postman.*

So postman.setNextRequest , works pm.setNextRequest will not

The postman app has auto suggest for pm.* , It shows available methods which makes scripting easier and fun

Comment: I'd recommend using all the `get` and `set` methods from the newer `pm.*` API rather than mixing and matching old and new. 

Comment: Updated, the answer x

Comment: Thanks. The new versions have auto suggestion in the sandbox to show which methods are available under that API.

Comment: @PDHide Perfect. This works. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Still using the old Postman libraries then the Following would also Work.

```
email_formatted = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("first_name") + '_' + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("last_name") + '@' + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("environment")+ 'gmail.com';
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("email", email_formatted);
console.log("Email: " + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("email"));
```